# How to check for null string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javascript global variable `selectedNode`. On click of a button I have to make ajax call but before that I have to check for null for `selectedNode`. If it is not null I have make ajax call. I have null in `selectedNode`, for that I have wrote if condition like this but its not working ,

```
alert("Selected Node: "+selectedNode);//<----Here it is showing null
if(!selectedNode || 0 === selectedNode.length){
    alert("Pease select any Vehicle");
    return;
}

// some ajax stuff
xmlHttpReqHT.open('GET', "HistoryTracing?node="+selectedNode+"&frmdate="+frmdat+"&todate="+todat, true);

//handling response
```

my problem is that, `selectedNode` is null, and skips the if block and makes ajax call with null value for `selectedNode`. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: As you can see from the answers grasping at straws, the code you posted is supposed to work as it is. Is this your actual code? Could `selectedNode` contain the *string* `"null"`?

Comment: That code should already work

Comment: `(!null || 0 === null.length)` returns true. Your check should work. Maybe `selectedNode` is `"null"`. In this case add `selectedNode === "null"` to your condition.

Comment: @Raghu If you check your variable through `alert(selectedNode)` you don't see a difference between `null` and `"null"`. In both cases the message box will display the same string.

Comment: @Raghu So its not null. I would recommend using the developer tools of your browser to check what value your variable really has.

Comment: There is no further discussion, use some debugger to check your variable ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
if(selectedNode !== null){
  // if not null or undefined code here
}
```

Or, to check empty string too, do like this:

```
if(selectedNode !== null || selectedNode !==''){
  // if not empty, not null or undefined code here
}
```

Or, to check empty strings `("")`, `null`, `undefined`, `false` and the numbers `0` and `NaN` do like below:

```
if(!selectedNode){
   //code here
}
```

Comment: I feel it strange, I tried `if(selectedNode!==null ){
     alert("select Vehicle");
     return;
    } `  it worked . can you explain how.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
if(selectedNode){
  // if not null code here
}
```

The above will look after all falsy values including empty string.